# Compile failed and ascii codec error when installing python scientific stack

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I was trying to install library requirements for the Stanford's online deep learning for NLP class http://cs224d.stanford.edu/assignment1/index.html

I tried to install using this command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Here's what in the requirements.txt:

```
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
certifi==14.05.14
gnureadline==6.3.3
ipython==3.0.0
matplotlib==1.4.3
mock==1.0.1
nose==1.3.4
numpy==1.9.2
pyparsing==2.0.3
python-dateutil==2.4.0
pytz==2014.10
pyzmq==14.4.1
scipy==0.14.1
six==1.9.0
tornado==4.0.2
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

With or withour sudo, and both on virtualenv and the standard environment, I always got the compile and ascii codec errors.

Here's the last few lines I got on my console:

> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/Modules/2.x/readline.o readline/libreadline.a readline/libhistory.a -lncurses -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/gnureadline.so
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

---

> Cleaning up...
>   Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, > tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip_build_root/gnureadline/setup.py';exec(compile(> getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), > **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Viw1GA-record/install- > record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error > code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/gnureadline
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in 
>      load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/**init**.py", line 235, in > main
>      return command.main(cmd_args)
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, > in main
>      text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 66: ordinal not in range(128)

Any insights on what those errors mean?

Comment: You should update pip, the latest version is 7.0.1, you are using `1.5.4`